# where is cakephp installed ubuntu10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, cakephp

I just did `apt-get install cakephp` and it installed cake php but I have no idea where the root directory is. How can I find that? I'm using ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 3):

```
dpkg -L cakephp
```

Or if you want to know which package installed a file, use dpkg -S:

```
user@host:~$ dpkg -S /usr/share/php/cake/libs
cakephp: /usr/share/php/cake/libs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name 'cake*'
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

locate is faster than find.

```
updatedb

locate cake
```

also

```
which cake
```